# How can I use old MIDI devices with modern PCs?

Tags: windows, serial, midi

I have a Yamaha PSR-550 keyboard. It was released in 2001 (it's as old as me!), and is equipped with MIDI ports:

[image]

How can I use the serial MIDI port (marked `to host`) with my modern PCs? (They don't have serial ports, and the keyboard appears to be using a non-standard pinout)

A copy of the manual with specifications (hosted on my webserver) can be found here: https://rahul.party/files/psr550-6044.pdf

Also see [this short article](http://faq.yamaha.com/us/en/article/musical-instruments/keyboards/digitalpianos/cvp_series/cvp96/311/1404/Differences_between_the_TO_HOST_port_and_MIDI_I-O_when_connecting_to_a_Personal_Computer/?current_page_id=1&sort=&type=) to learn more about the port.

Comment: [MIDI Connection | How to Connect a MIDI Keyboard to a Computer](https://www.musicrepo.com/how-to-connect-midi-keyboard-to-computer/)

Comment: Did you google your question title? If not, why not? :)

Comment: @david I did, couldn't find anything about _serial_ midi

Comment: So what's stopping you using the midi out port?

Comment: @david the fact that there are no cheap USB→MIDI cables available in India. Also, I'd like to learn how one might go about using the serial port regardless, since it obviously exists for a reason.

Comment: You can buy a serial to USB adapter. Note "Some old synth models (mainly by Yamaha) have a To Host connector that allows to connect the synth to serial port (COM, RS-232) of computer. As with USB connection, for the synth to function as a MIDI keyboard in this case, it requires a driver which usually comes with the synth.

This connection method is currently obsolete since the physical-level connection itself is obsolete — due to extremely low data-transfer rate, most of modern computers are not equipped with the serial interface (somewhen it has been used to connect a mouse)."

Answer (score 1):

Electrically, the "To Host" port uses RS-232 signals (when in PC mode), so you could connect it to any COM port with a simple cable.

However, the drivers that make this port available as a MIDI port are quite old, and work only with ISA(-compatible) COM ports integrated on the PC motherboard. So unless you have such an old PC, the only reasonable way is to use a USB/MIDI adapter instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need a USB to MiDI adapter. I have used this [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0017H4EBG) and can personally say it works with my Casio and Yamaha keyboards.

You will also need MIDI software, such as [Anvil Studio](http://www.anvilstudio.com/indexm.htm).  I have used the free version of Anvil Studio and can also say it works with the MIDI adapter and my keyboards.

Comment: The linked adapter has no optocoupler, and does not support receiving running status or SysEx messages.